# GLUT Window not showing up in Eclipse

Tags: opengl, window, glut

I'm a beginner and I followed an online tutorial to download GLUT and install MinGW, etc.

The tutorial provided me with some sample code, but when I run it nothing shows up at all. I've built the project (Ctrl-B) and made sure all the libraries were imported.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>


const int WIDTH = 600;
const int HEIGHT = 480;

/* Prototypes */
void init();
void display();

/* Definitions */

/* Initializes the OpenGL state */
void init() {
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ); /* Set the clear color */
}

/* Displays a black clear screen */
void display() {
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT ); /* Clear the screen with the clear color */
    glutSwapBuffers(); /* Double buffering */
}

/* The main function */
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    /* Glut setup function calls */
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB ); /* Use double buffering and RGB            
        colors */
    glutInitWindowPosition( 100, 100 );
    glutInitWindowSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc( display );  /* Call back display function */
    glutMainLoop(); /* Continue drawing the scene */
    return 0;
}
```

I press run and it says "launching GLUTDemo.exe" then nothing happens.